# Google sheets Filter formula for text containing

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I am unable to make the below filter formula work. Notice that I am trying to refer to the sheet "Data" and filter them into another sheet. I get error saying there were no matches.

```
=FILTER(Data!A3:Data!J, ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXMATCH(Data!J3:Data!J, ".*km.*")))
```

However, the above formula works when I insert it in the "Data" sheet. Notice that "Data!" is removed as it is in same sheet.

```
=FILTER(A3:J, ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXMATCH(J3:J, ".*km.*")))
```

I tried using the below sets with same results.

```
=FILTER(A3:J, REGEXMATCH(J3:J, ".*km.*"))
=FILTER(Data!A3:Data!J, REGEXMATCH(Data!J3:Data!J, ".*km.*"))
```

I have no problems filtering dates, numbers from "Data" sheet into my filtering sheet. It is only with "text contains" condition. Any help to resolve this is appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The formula was wrong. I was using the "Data!" twice. The below code works. Phew! Switching between languages (autohotkey, html, javascript, LibreOffice basic) seems to be taking a toll.

```
=FILTER(Data!A3:J, REGEXMATCH(Data!J3:J, ".*km.*"))
```